# DB2 "With UR" Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, spring-data, isolation-level

I am using a Spring Data Repository interface to retrieve data from DB2 (z/OS). I have a couple of methods that rely on the method signatues and one that relies on an explicit @Query.

How do I make the SQL generated have the "WITH UR" clause?
I added @Transactional(isolation=Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED) on the line above the @Query annotation and also above the two methods but it doesn't seem to append the clause to the generated SQL.

Thanks

Comment: were you able to get solution for this? If yes can you post your solution.

Comment: Sorry...we moved away from Spring Data to conventional JPQL the following year.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to do this on a query by query basis was through the usage of Hibernate comments hint and a custom Dialect.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.7 with spring-data-jpa 2.7.12.

In your Repository interface, use [@QueryHints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.7.12/reference/html/#jpa.query-hints) and @QueryHint annotations above your Repository methods.

```
@QueryHints(value = {
        @QueryHint(name=org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints.HINT_COMMENT, value=DB2zOSCustomDialect.UNCOMMITTED_READ)})
Optional<MyEntity> findByProperty(String property);
```

The custom dialect class should be extended from DB2390Dialect and a straight forward implementation is provided below (not thoroughly tested).

```
public class DB2zOSCustomDialect extends DB2390Dialect{

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    public static final String UNCOMMITTED_READ = "with ur";
    
    @Override 
    public String addSqlHintOrComment(java.lang.String sql, QueryParameters parameters, boolean commentsEnabled){
        String uncommittedRead = parameters.getComment();
    
        if(uncommittedRead != null && uncommittedRead.equalsIgnoreCase(UNCOMMITTED_READ)) {
            parameters.setComment(null);
            return super.addSqlHintOrComment(sql, parameters, commentsEnabled) + " " + UNCOMMITTED_READ;
        } else {
            return super.addSqlHintOrComment(sql, parameters, commentsEnabled);
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't need to check query by query, a custom Dialect extended from DB2390Dialect overring *transformSelectString* method from [Dialect](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/Dialect.html) class should suffice.